# Undefined function or variable 'exp2fit'

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, exponential-distribution

I'm new to MATLAB and I am trying to use the `exp2fit` function, but the command window throws the following error:

> Undefined function or variable 'exp2fit'.
>
> Error in myscript (line 34)
>
> s=exp2fit(t,f,1);

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the function, but does `fit(t,f,'exp2')` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not built-in to MATLAB. You need to download it from the [MATLAB File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21959-exponential-fit-without-start-guess/content/exp2fit.m). Then you need to either put it somewhere in your MATLAB PATH or in the same folder as the function you are executing.